# Using Javascript library(jsPDF) with Ruby-on-Rails views

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, jspdf

I am new to ROR, JS and for web techs overall. I am trying to build a simple ROR app where i want to generate a PDF file at client side. I found [this](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) javascript library suitable for my purpose. I installed this dependancy using `bower`. Now I am not sure how do i use this library in my `views` ? 
I have tried searching over internet but could not find anything conclusive.

I am using Rails version 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the zip from the GIT repos. Extract the zip file there is a folder **examples**.

Just view the code of **basic.html**

You need to add this (jspdf.debug.js) (dist/jspdf.debug.js) file in your **app/assets/javascripts**

require this file in **application.js**

Then try like this in your view........

```
<a href="#" class="button">Run Code</a>

<script>

$(function() {
  $('.button').on('click',function(){   
    var name = prompt('What is your name?');
    var multiplier = prompt('Enter a number:');
    multiplier = parseInt(multiplier);

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.setFontSize(22);    
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Questions');
    doc.setFontSize(16);
    doc.text(20, 30, 'This belongs to: ' + name);

    for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i ++) {
        doc.text(20, 30 + (i * 10), i + ' x ' + multiplier + ' = ___');
    }

    doc.addPage();
    doc.setFontSize(22);
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Answers');
    doc.setFontSize(16);

    for (i = 1; i <= 12; i ++) {
        doc.text(20, 30 + (i * 10), i + ' x ' + multiplier + ' = ' + (i * multiplier));
    }
    doc.save('Test.pdf');

});
});


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. I get an error in dev tools saying `demoUserInput()` function is not defined !

Comment: @AbhishekBansal : I updated my answer please check. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `javascript_include_tag` to include it in your view. Reference [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag)

Download the zip from the GIT repos. Extract and put the **jspdf.js** file in your `vendor/assets/javascripts`. Then either use above method to include it in specific view or require it in application.js like:

```
//= require jspdf
```

Comment: thanks for this.. but i am confused about later part.. what to do after this ?

Comment: Using this code `//= require jspdf` will make your JS file available globally. After that you can follow the instructions given in Github for the usage. Eg: `var doc = new jsPDF();` so on

Comment: I tried doing that as per @Akshay's answer but it still is not working.

Comment: Are you talking about this error **demoUserInput() function is not defined**. Then try putting the code inside application.js for time being and check if its working.

Comment: tried putting script in application.js Still got same error!